# why space is not counted in String.length in java code?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

Im quite confused with a simple problem. when i use space in my String, the String.length method just calculate the string length before the space, why?? for example it returns length of "ab cdef", 2, while it seems to be 7! I want to know the string length with the space,
here is my simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter Operation: ");
    String value = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(valuee.length());
}// psv main
```

Also, if i want to remove space in string,

```
String valuee = value.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

does not work!
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you print length before replacing or after?

Comment: it do not matter where replace is used!

Comment: you should use a debugger to find out what's really going on in your code, to validate your assumptions.

Answer (score 5):

A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. You can change the delimiter using the `useDelimiter` method

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n"); // use new line as delimiter instead of white space
    System.out.println("Please Enter Operation: ");
    String value = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(value.length());
```

You could even use `nextLine()` which has a new line as delimiter by default

Answer (score 2):

Please use the nextLine() instead of next().
Here is Code Snips

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String scannedValue = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(scannedValue.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

next() ignores the trailing space, change next to nextLine().

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter Operation: ");
    String value = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(valuee.length());
}// psv main
```

For removing space, try

```
String valuee = value.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is not with the length() method of the String class, it's the method you are using to read the input which scans the input before the spaces. If you add the space manually it works. as follows:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter Operation: ");
    String value = scanner.next();
    value = value + "     ";
    System.out.println(value.length());
```

For removing the spaces you can use:

```
value.replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

It seems, `Scanner.Next` method considers `white space` for identifying the token.

See below example

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Post4 {

    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter Operation: ");
        String value = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(value.length());
        value = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(value.length());
        
        
    }// psv main
}
```

for below input

> asd asdf

the output is

> 3
>
> 4

Use `Scanner.nextLine();` to get the input and use

`String.replaceAll(" ", "")` to replace `whitespace`.

Have a look at the `Scanner` class constructor, it is using `whitespace`

```
public Scanner(InputStream source) {
        this(new InputStreamReader(source), WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
    }
```

you can change the delimiter.

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
```